# Unpermitted Parameters with Hashes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters

I have a hash field in my Rails model and am attempting to update it.
The attribute, `detail`, was first generated through a migration as a `text` type. Afterwords, in my model, it was set as a `hash` through the `store :detail` property

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    store :detail
end
```

My strong_params are as such:

```
params.require(:request).permit(:name, :action, :detail => {})
```

However, when my Parameters go through as

```
Parameters: {"request"=>{"name"=>"temp", "action"=>"create", "detail"=>{"test"=>"fdsf"}}}
```

I am told that there is an `Unpermitted parameter: test`, despite the `test` parameter being part of the `detail` hash.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The weird thing is I can save the record successfully in the Rails console but when trying to do so through the app I get the "Unpermitted parameter" error. Perhaps due to the fact that the field type is "text" while I am trying to save a hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
params.require(:request).permit(:name, :action, detail: [:test])
```

Another option (e. g. if you do not know the possible field names in advance) would be to serialize the `detail` to json string on client side, accept it as string and deserialize to a hash afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This (rather old) [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454) tackles your problem quite interestingly

Considering your hash consists of more values than `:test` you could try the solution  with `.tap`

```
params.require(:request).permit(:name, :action).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:detail] = params[:request][:detail]
end
```

Or the somewhat less dynamic:

```
params.require(:request).permit(:name, :action, :detail => [:test])
```

This [blogpost](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html) sums up different approaches.

**edit**

You need your `detail` column to be of type 'text' to be able to save the hash as a string. In your `Request` model add this to the top:

```
serialize :detail
```

as it will allow to interpret the stringified `:detail` as a hash

Comment: I tried doing your whitelist solution and the same issue popped up... it does seem preferred though with how i don't have to list all the values.

Comment: Have you checked the 'edit' part of my answer? ;) how the value is stored in the db is not handled by what parameters you permit for your object.